# yaml params edit with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have a list of yaml files which I would like to edit in the same way. Put the following block under spec.template.imagePullSecret and spec.template.container.imagePullPolicy in each file:

```
imagePullSecrets: 
  - dockerpullsecret
container:
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

This is an example of one file:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
meta data:
  name: sensor-finanda-ci
  namespace: argo-events
spec:  
  template:
    serviceAccountName: argo-events-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: eventsource-iv
      eventSourceName: eventsource-iv
      eventName: iv
```

This is my desired output:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
meta data:
  name: sensor-finanda-ci
  namespace: argo-events
spec:  
  template:
    serviceAccountName: argo-events-sa
    imagePullSecrets: 
      - dockerpullsecret
    container:
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  dependencies:
    - name: eventsource-iv
      eventSourceName: eventsource-iv
      eventName: iv
```

Comment: I don't know even how to start, I am looking for suggestions.....

Answer (score 0):

If your heart is set on a Python solution, something like this might do:

```py
import os
import yaml

for yaml_filename in [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.endswith('.yaml')]:
    with open(yaml_filename, 'r') as yaml_file:
        yaml_obj = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)

    if 'spec' not in yaml_obj:
        yaml_obj['spec'] = {"template": {}}
    if 'template' not in yaml_obj['spec']:
        yaml_obj['spec']['template'] = {"imagePullSecrets": [], "container": {}}
    if 'container' not in yaml_obj['spec']['template']:
        yaml_obj['spec']['template']['container'] = {}

    yaml_obj['spec']['template']['imagePullSecrets'] = ["dockerpullsecret"]
    yaml_obj['spec']['template']['container']['imagePullPolicy'] = 'IfNotPresent'

    with open(yaml_filename, 'w') as yaml_file:
        yaml.dump(yaml_obj, yaml_file)
```

If you're open to command-line utils, this is more concise:

Loop over the files and use [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) to edit them in-place.

```sh
for file in *.yaml; do 
  yq -i e '.spec.template.imagePullSecrets = ["dockerpullsecret"] | .spec.template.container.imagePullPolicy = "IfNotPresent"' "$file"
done
```